# spacemacs themes auto deleted?

Tags: spacemacs

using meta + x then package install I tried installing a theme. I am able to apply it and it looks great... problem is if i restart spacemacs the following happens:

Found 1 orphan package(s) to delete...
--> deleting color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow... [1/1]

anyone know how to fix this? I tried googling and changing my settings (specially this setting dotspacemacs-install-packages 'used-only)), but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't install packages with package install. See the FAQ here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/FAQ.org#why-are-packages-installed-with-package-install-automatically-deleted-by-spacemacs-when-it-boots

Instead, install packages with `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`, or create a layer, or set the variable `dotspacemacs-install-packages` to `used-but-keep-unused` which will prevent Spacemacs from removing the packages you installed manually.

As for themes, just install the `themes-megapack` layer to get a bunch of different themes. The page for it is here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes/themes-megapack